# Как из списка, в котором много словарей, получить n данные из n словаря?

Tags: python, list, словари

Есть список, в котором 129 словарей. Нужно вывести определенные данные из каждого словаря. Например:

`{'id': 129, 'name': 'npc_dota_hero_mars', 'localized_name': 'Mars', 'primary_attr': 'str', 'attack_type': 'Melee', 'roles': ['Carry', 'Initiator', 'Disabler', 'Durable'], 'legs': 2}`

Это последний словарь в списке. Его и первый я вывести могу, а как вывести все? И мне, например, нужны только данные `id`, `localized_name` из каждого, а остальное не нужно. Как реализовать?

Пример кода:

```
def pars():
    response = requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/heroes")
    data = response.json()
    a = {}
    for index in data:
        for slovar in index:
            a.update(index)
    return a

print(pars())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
def pars():
    response = requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/heroes")
    data = response.json()
    return {index['id']:index['localized_name'] for index in data}
k = pars()
print(k)
```

Результат:

```
{1: 'Anti-Mage', 2: 'Axe', 3: 'Bane', 4: 'Bloodseeker', 5: 'Crystal Maiden', 6:'Drow Ranger', 7: 'Earthshaker', 8: 'Juggernaut', 9: 'Mirana', 10: 'Morphling',11: 'Shadow Fiend', 12: 'Phantom Lancer', 13: 'Puck', 14: 'Pudge', 15: 'Razor',16: 'Sand King', 17: 'Storm Spirit', 18: 'Sven', 19: 'Tiny', 20: 'Vengeful Spirit', 21: 'Windranger', 22: 'Zeus', 23: 'Kunkka', 25: 'Lina', 26: 'Lion', 27: 'Shadow Shaman', 28: 'Slardar', 29: 'Tidehunter', 30: 'Witch Doctor', 31: 'Lich', 32: 'Riki', 33: 'Enigma', 34: 'Tinker', 35: 'Sniper', 36: 'Necrophos', 37: 'Warlock', 38: 'Beastmaster', 39: 'Queen of Pain', 40: 'Venomancer', 41: 'Faceless Void', 42: 'Wraith King', 43: 'Death Prophet', 44: 'Phantom Assassin', 45: 'Pugna',46: 'Templar Assassin', 47: 'Viper', 48: 'Luna', 49: 'Dragon Knight', 50: 'Dazzle', 51: 'Clockwerk', 52: 'Leshrac', 53: "Nature's Prophet", 54: 'Lifestealer', 55: 'Dark Seer', 56: 'Clinkz', 57: 'Omniknight', 58: 'Enchantress', 59: 'Huskar', 60: 'Night Stalker', 61: 'Broodmother', 62: 'Bounty Hunter', 63: 'Weaver', 64:'Jakiro', 65: 'Batrider', 66: 'Chen', 67: 'Spectre', 68: 'Ancient Apparition', 69: 'Doom', 70: 'Ursa', 71: 'Spirit Breaker', 72: 'Gyrocopter', 73: 'Alchemist',74: 'Invoker', 75: 'Silencer', 76: 'Outworld Devourer', 77: 'Lycan', 78: 'Brewmaster', 79: 'Shadow Demon', 80: 'Lone Druid', 81: 'Chaos Knight', 82: 'Meepo', 83: 'Treant Protector', 84: 'Ogre Magi', 85: 'Undying', 86: 'Rubick', 87: 'Disruptor', 88: 'Nyx Assassin', 89: 'Naga Siren', 90: 'Keeper of the Light', 91: 'Io',92: 'Visage', 93: 'Slark', 94: 'Medusa', 95: 'Troll Warlord', 96: 'Centaur Warrunner', 97: 'Magnus', 98: 'Timbersaw', 99: 'Bristleback', 100: 'Tusk', 101: 'Skywrath Mage', 102: 'Abaddon', 103: 'Elder Titan', 104: 'Legion Commander', 105: 'Techies', 106: 'Ember Spirit', 107: 'Earth Spirit', 108: 'Underlord', 109: 'Terrorblade', 110: 'Phoenix', 111: 'Oracle', 112: 'Winter Wyvern', 113: 'Arc Warden', 114: 'Monkey King', 119: 'Dark Willow', 120: 'Pangolier', 121: 'Grimstroke', 126: 'Void Spirit', 128: 'Snapfire', 129: 'Mars'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [18]: res = [{k:d[k] for k in d if k in ["id", "localized_name"]} for d in data]

In [19]: res
Out[19]:
[{'id': 1, 'localized_name': 'Anti-Mage'},
 {'id': 2, 'localized_name': 'Axe'},
 {'id': 3, 'localized_name': 'Bane'},
 {'id': 4, 'localized_name': 'Bloodseeker'},
 {'id': 5, 'localized_name': 'Crystal Maiden'},
 {'id': 6, 'localized_name': 'Drow Ranger'},
 {'id': 7, 'localized_name': 'Earthshaker'},
 {'id': 8, 'localized_name': 'Juggernaut'},
 {'id': 9, 'localized_name': 'Mirana'},
 {'id': 10, 'localized_name': 'Morphling'},
 {'id': 11, 'localized_name': 'Shadow Fiend'},
 {'id': 12, 'localized_name': 'Phantom Lancer'},
 {'id': 13, 'localized_name': 'Puck'},
 {'id': 14, 'localized_name': 'Pudge'},
 {'id': 15, 'localized_name': 'Razor'},
 {'id': 16, 'localized_name': 'Sand King'},
 {'id': 17, 'localized_name': 'Storm Spirit'},
 {'id': 18, 'localized_name': 'Sven'},
 {'id': 19, 'localized_name': 'Tiny'},
 {'id': 20, 'localized_name': 'Vengeful Spirit'},
 {'id': 21, 'localized_name': 'Windranger'},
 {'id': 22, 'localized_name': 'Zeus'},
 {'id': 23, 'localized_name': 'Kunkka'},
 {'id': 25, 'localized_name': 'Lina'},
 {'id': 26, 'localized_name': 'Lion'},
 {'id': 27, 'localized_name': 'Shadow Shaman'},
 {'id': 28, 'localized_name': 'Slardar'},
 {'id': 29, 'localized_name': 'Tidehunter'},
 {'id': 30, 'localized_name': 'Witch Doctor'},
 {'id': 31, 'localized_name': 'Lich'},
 {'id': 32, 'localized_name': 'Riki'},
 {'id': 33, 'localized_name': 'Enigma'},
 {'id': 34, 'localized_name': 'Tinker'},
 {'id': 35, 'localized_name': 'Sniper'},
 {'id': 36, 'localized_name': 'Necrophos'},
 {'id': 37, 'localized_name': 'Warlock'},
 {'id': 38, 'localized_name': 'Beastmaster'},
 {'id': 39, 'localized_name': 'Queen of Pain'},
 {'id': 40, 'localized_name': 'Venomancer'},
 {'id': 41, 'localized_name': 'Faceless Void'},
 {'id': 42, 'localized_name': 'Wraith King'},
 {'id': 43, 'localized_name': 'Death Prophet'},
 {'id': 44, 'localized_name': 'Phantom Assassin'},
 {'id': 45, 'localized_name': 'Pugna'},
 {'id': 46, 'localized_name': 'Templar Assassin'},
 {'id': 47, 'localized_name': 'Viper'},
 {'id': 48, 'localized_name': 'Luna'},
 {'id': 49, 'localized_name': 'Dragon Knight'},
 {'id': 50, 'localized_name': 'Dazzle'},
 {'id': 51, 'localized_name': 'Clockwerk'},
 {'id': 52, 'localized_name': 'Leshrac'},
 {'id': 53, 'localized_name': "Nature's Prophet"},
 {'id': 54, 'localized_name': 'Lifestealer'},
 {'id': 55, 'localized_name': 'Dark Seer'},
 {'id': 56, 'localized_name': 'Clinkz'},
 {'id': 57, 'localized_name': 'Omniknight'},
 {'id': 58, 'localized_name': 'Enchantress'},
 {'id': 59, 'localized_name': 'Huskar'},
 {'id': 60, 'localized_name': 'Night Stalker'},
 {'id': 61, 'localized_name': 'Broodmother'},
 {'id': 62, 'localized_name': 'Bounty Hunter'},
 {'id': 63, 'localized_name': 'Weaver'},
 {'id': 64, 'localized_name': 'Jakiro'},
 {'id': 65, 'localized_name': 'Batrider'},
 {'id': 66, 'localized_name': 'Chen'},
 {'id': 67, 'localized_name': 'Spectre'},
 {'id': 68, 'localized_name': 'Ancient Apparition'},
 {'id': 69, 'localized_name': 'Doom'},
 {'id': 70, 'localized_name': 'Ursa'},
 {'id': 71, 'localized_name': 'Spirit Breaker'},
 {'id': 72, 'localized_name': 'Gyrocopter'},
 {'id': 73, 'localized_name': 'Alchemist'},
 {'id': 74, 'localized_name': 'Invoker'},
 {'id': 75, 'localized_name': 'Silencer'},
 {'id': 76, 'localized_name': 'Outworld Devourer'},
 {'id': 77, 'localized_name': 'Lycan'},
 {'id': 78, 'localized_name': 'Brewmaster'},
 {'id': 79, 'localized_name': 'Shadow Demon'},
 {'id': 80, 'localized_name': 'Lone Druid'},
 {'id': 81, 'localized_name': 'Chaos Knight'},
 {'id': 82, 'localized_name': 'Meepo'},
 {'id': 83, 'localized_name': 'Treant Protector'},
 {'id': 84, 'localized_name': 'Ogre Magi'},
 {'id': 85, 'localized_name': 'Undying'},
 {'id': 86, 'localized_name': 'Rubick'},
 {'id': 87, 'localized_name': 'Disruptor'},
 {'id': 88, 'localized_name': 'Nyx Assassin'},
 {'id': 89, 'localized_name': 'Naga Siren'},
 {'id': 90, 'localized_name': 'Keeper of the Light'},
 {'id': 91, 'localized_name': 'Io'},
 {'id': 92, 'localized_name': 'Visage'},
 {'id': 93, 'localized_name': 'Slark'},
 {'id': 94, 'localized_name': 'Medusa'},
 {'id': 95, 'localized_name': 'Troll Warlord'},
 {'id': 96, 'localized_name': 'Centaur Warrunner'},
 {'id': 97, 'localized_name': 'Magnus'},
 {'id': 98, 'localized_name': 'Timbersaw'},
 {'id': 99, 'localized_name': 'Bristleback'},
 {'id': 100, 'localized_name': 'Tusk'},
 {'id': 101, 'localized_name': 'Skywrath Mage'},
 {'id': 102, 'localized_name': 'Abaddon'},
 {'id': 103, 'localized_name': 'Elder Titan'},
 {'id': 104, 'localized_name': 'Legion Commander'},
 {'id': 105, 'localized_name': 'Techies'},
 {'id': 106, 'localized_name': 'Ember Spirit'},
 {'id': 107, 'localized_name': 'Earth Spirit'},
 {'id': 108, 'localized_name': 'Underlord'},
 {'id': 109, 'localized_name': 'Terrorblade'},
 {'id': 110, 'localized_name': 'Phoenix'},
 {'id': 111, 'localized_name': 'Oracle'},
 {'id': 112, 'localized_name': 'Winter Wyvern'},
 {'id': 113, 'localized_name': 'Arc Warden'},
 {'id': 114, 'localized_name': 'Monkey King'},
 {'id': 119, 'localized_name': 'Dark Willow'},
 {'id': 120, 'localized_name': 'Pangolier'},
 {'id': 121, 'localized_name': 'Grimstroke'},
 {'id': 126, 'localized_name': 'Void Spirit'},
 {'id': 128, 'localized_name': 'Snapfire'},
 {'id': 129, 'localized_name': 'Mars'}]
```